# Namespaced Collections in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, namespaces, meteor, minimongo

I'm currently developing a Meteor application which will be based on different packages (maybe created by different developers).

My question is if there's a meteor'ish way to namespace collections so that they won't collide with other available collections.

For example, I have a package which uses the collection with the name 'todos' and another one which may also include a collection with the name 'todos'. Is there a way to namespace these collections (e.g. with their package-Name prepended)?

I've found out that there's an option for namespacing in MongoDB with a '.':
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#what-is-a-namespace-in-mongodb

Is this also the best way to namespace collections in Meteor?

Coming to Meteor with a Rails background, I can remember that you can create namespaced Engines in rails (which also creates namespaced database-Tables). Is there something similar in Meteor?

The closest I came was with this Issue I've found:
https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-gridfs/issues/6

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes MongoDB doesn't allow you to create namespaced collections (except for databases) and so doesn't Meteor.

Comment: Unless you want to namespace them manually in the string name (ex.: "bobbyApp_questions" and "aliceApp_questions" - no access separation or anything)

Comment: So use separate databases if it is appropriate.

Comment: This package https://atmospherejs.com/package/dbproxy might help.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I think I'll stick with the prepending of the namespace to the collection-Name (such as 'fooCollection' or 'foo_collection')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a period in the collection name is a perfectly fine namespacing scheme for Meteor collections just as it is if you were using MongoDB alone.

```
var TodoCollection = Meteor.Collection('packageName.todos');
```

Packages such as CollectionFS use this technique to avoid collection name collisions.

Comment: Thank you! Beforehand I've used things such as Meteor.Collection('fooBarBaz');. The dot-Notation made it much clearer and it also feels better.